# trigger to calculate end time with a duration from another table

Tags: mysql

I want to do a trigger to calculate a endtime, from a start time that is on the same table and a duration that is in another table.

My table Agenda has (Serv, Date, Starttime, Endtime) and my Service table has (ID_Serv, Price, Duration)

I don't understand much of mysql and this code don't work, can you help me

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Calc_Endtime 
BEFORE INSERT ON Agenda
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE Agenda

    SET NEW.Endtime = ADDTIME ( NEW.Starttime, Service.Duration)
WHERE ID_Serv = NEW.Serv;

END $$
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a confusion about some elements of mysql here, the following lines are without testing against the missing table definitions:

```
...
BEGIN
 NEW.Endtime = (SELECT ADDTIME(NEW.Starttime, Duration) 
                 FROM Service WHERE ID_Serv = NEW.Serv);
END $$
```